# Error from plsql block when making request to secured host

Tags: sql, oracle, http, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make request https host, before writing my PL/SQL block below is my work around.

I connected to DB as sysdba

`grant execute on utl_http to <user>;`

and I ran below script

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
 BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL
 (
  ACL         => 'oraclecloud_wallet.xml',
  DESCRIPTION => 'Permissions to access https://XXXX.oraclecloud.com',
  PRINCIPAL   => 'SWIFT_LOCAL',
  IS_GRANT    => TRUE,
  PRIVILEGE   => 'connect',
  START_DATE  => NULL,
  END_DATE    => NULL
  );
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE
(
  ACL       => 'oraclecloud_wallet.xml',
  PRINCIPAL => 'SWIFT_LOCAL',
  IS_GRANT  => true,
  PRIVILEGE => 'resolve'
);

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL
(
  ACL  => 'oraclecloud_wallet.xml',
  HOST => '*.oraclecloud.com'
);

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_WALLET_ACL
(
  ACL         => 'oraclecloud_wallet.xml',
  WALLET_PATH => 'file:C:\app\wallet'
);

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occurred while creating ACL: '|| SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

I downloaded certificate and kept in local folder C:\app\wallet.

I created a directory in DB by `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CER_DIR AS 'C:\app\wallet';`

Then I ran below PL/SQL block

`set SERVEROUTPUT on;
        DECLARE
        lo_req  UTL_HTTP.req;
        lo_resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
        BEGIN
        UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET ('file:C:\app\wallet');
        lo_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://XXXX.oraclecloud.com');
        lo_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(lo_req);
        dbms_output.put_line(lo_resp.status_code);
        UTL_HTTP.end_response(lo_resp);
       END;`

Now I am getting following error

`Error report -
    ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
    ORA-28759: failure to open file
    ORA-06512: at line 6
    29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
    *Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
    *Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
               Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.`

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. It would be great help.

Comment: "kept in local folder C:\app\wallet" - is that folder on the database server, and accessible by the Oracle process? The 'local' suggests maybe the server is elsewhere and you're trying to access a local (on your client PC) file from a remote DB server?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am trying in my local PC, I install Oracle 11 g and locally I am trying to requesting host and the folder is in my local PC. How can I check the folder is accessible by Oracle process. I thought it is accessible as I am doing everything in local.

Comment: @AlexPoole I got to know that I missed to create a wallet and Add certificates to wallet. we can create wallet by command 'orapki'. When I tried to run that command I am getting 'unknown command' error, can any one help me please